# Tableviewcells actions xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

so I am currently making a TODO app. currently having issues making my `tableView` cells clickable or "tappable". I run the simulator and it seems that the code doesnt fully work. I keep clicking on each cell and it does nothing. What I want is each TODO item in each cell to be clickable and go to ask.com to be search as it is in my code. But it seems that this particular function is not working and I don't know what to do. if someone could fix this issue for me it would be great. Source code would be amazing. Thanks in advance. also I am new to code. I will "**" the part of code I think is wrong and doesn't work. I tried using 'didSelectRowAt' delegate if this is correct it also maybe due to the placement of the code but again I am not sure. I included everything relevant. Thanks

```
import UIKit
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController, NewCellDelegate, {
    var news:[News]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadData()

        func loadData() {
            news = [News]()
            news = DataManager.loadAll(News.self).sorted(by: {$0.createdAt < $1.createdAt})
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

        @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
            let addAlert = UIAlertController(title: "ADD", message: "TODO", preferredStyle: .alert)
            addAlert.addTextField { (textfield:UITextField) in
                textfield.placeholder = "TODO"
            }

            addAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                guard let title = addAlert.textFields?.first?.text else {return}
                let newsave = News(title: title, completed: false, createdAt: Date(), itemIdentifier: UUID())
                newsave.saveItem()
                self.news.append(newsave)

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: 0)

                self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


            }))

            addAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            self.present(addAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    };

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return news.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell
        cell.delegte = self

        let news = self.news[indexPath.row]

        cell.label.text = news.title

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:
            NSIndexPath) {
        //getting the index path of selected row
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        //getting the current cell from the index path
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

        //getting the text of that cell
        let TODO = currentCell.textLabel!.text

        let appURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.ask.com/web?q=\
            (TODO))&o=0&qo=homepageSearchBox)")

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL! as URL) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(appURL! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL! as URL)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat the code and remove the bold tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are using wrong didselect method, use below one**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{'your code'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

And also set its delegate and datasource,

tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self